# Concatenate rows bases on sequence number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for example like below:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    SeqNumber INT, 
    Note VARCHAR(MAX),
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @T (SeqNumber, Note, UserID) VALUES
(1, 'A', 20),
(2, 'B', 20),
(1, 'F', 20),
(2, 'K', 20),
(3, 'M', 20),
(1, 'X', 20),
(1, 'Y', 20)
```

I wish to create the result as below:

```
UserID   ResultNotes
20       'AB'
20       'FKM'
20       'X'
20       'Y'
```

Do you know how to achieve this in MS SQL Server (T-SQL)? It can be in MS SQL Server 2016 or earlier.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this can really be done with just the information in your table, because there is no logic by which `B` should be associated with `A` any more than `K` should be.

Comment: Are you aware, that there is no implicit sort order? it seems that you want to start a *new group* when the SeqNumber is a `1`. So A and B are the first group, FKM the second and so on. But without an additional sort order or any kind of grouping key **this set is not ordered!**. This may return in any random order...

Comment: I agree with Tim and Shnugo - this can't be done with this table in a reliable way. Database tables are unsorted by nature - so without adding another column to indicate the order of the rows, or the groups, it really can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a comment in the beginning, but I decided to prepare an answer out of this...

Are you aware, that there is no implicit sort order? it seems that you want to start a *new group* when the SeqNumber is a `1`. So - in your sample - A and B are the first group, FKM the second and so on. But without an additional sort order or any kind of grouping key **this set is not ordered!**. This may return in any random order...

This was the approach with a grouping key using [`STRING_AGG` (needs v2017+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    GroupKey INT,
    SeqNumber INT, 
    Note VARCHAR(MAX),
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @T (GroupKey,SeqNumber, Note, UserID) VALUES
(1, 1, 'A', 20),
(1, 2, 'B', 20),
(2, 1, 'F', 20),
(2, 2, 'K', 20),
(2, 3, 'M', 20),
(3, 1, 'X', 20),
(4, 1, 'Y', 20);

SELECT t.UserID
      ,STRING_AGG(Note,'') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.SeqNumber) AS ResultNotes
FROM @T t
GROUP BY t.GroupKey,t.UserID;
```

And this works in a version before 2017:

```
SELECT t.UserID
     ,(
        SELECT t2.Note AS [*]
        FROM @T t2
        WHERE t.GroupKey=t2.GroupKey
          AND t.UserID=t2.UserID
        ORDER BY t2.SeqNumber
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
      ).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS ResultNotes
FROM @T t
GROUP BY t.GroupKey,t.UserID
```

### UPDATE: Create a GroupingKey out of a fix order

See this code how to create a grouping key, if the sort order is fixed (in my case by an `IDENTITY`-ID):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    SeqNumber INT, 
    Note VARCHAR(MAX),
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @T (SeqNumber, Note, UserID) VALUES
(1, 'A', 20),
(2, 'B', 20),
(1, 'F', 20),
(2, 'K', 20),
(3, 'M', 20),
(1, 'X', 20),
(1, 'Y', 20);

WITH Get1s AS --set a group key per "1"
(
    SELECT t.ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS GroupKey
    FROM @T t
    WHERE t.SeqNumber=1
)
SELECT *
      ,(SELECT MAX(x.GroupKey) FROM Get1s x WHERE t.ID>=x.ID) AS GroupKey
FROM @T t;
```

In the next step you can use this grouping key in an approach like above...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    SeqNumber INT, 
    Note VARCHAR(MAX),
    UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @T (SeqNumber, Note, UserID) VALUES
(1, 'A', 20),
(2, 'B', 20),
(1, 'F', 20),
(2, 'K', 20),
(3, 'M', 20),
(1, 'X', 20),
(1, 'Y', 20)

drop table if exists #d

select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY userid ASC) AS Row#, case when SeqNumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end as t , SeqNumber,note,userid into #d from @t 
select userid,string_agg(Note,'') from
(

select isnull(t + (select sum(t) from #d as g where g.row# < #d.row#),1) as s , SeqNumber,note,userid from #d
) j
 group by s,userid
```

Comment: No! This is a really dangerous approach! This might work in all your tests but breaks in production with silly and hardly findable errors. **The set is not sorted!** Your code uses `order by userid` in an `OVER`clause. This shows clearly, that you are relying on the given order as `UserID` is not unique. Never rely on the random sort order of any set. The only guaranteed order is the one you specify yourself using `ORDER BY` with (a) suitable column(s) with unique values.

Comment: I don't accept. The question itself doesn't indicate what should we do when there is any break between userids. I assumed that we should consider them as a separator.

Comment: You did not get the ghist... **Your approach is completely random**.Exactly the same input can produce absolutely different results. The most dangerous part is: This **will** work... It will work **in most cases**. This will pass all your tests. But still you cannot rely on it. Never do this in a real system if it is not a *one-time-action*...

Comment: What should I do when there is not any reliable column for ordering? I think the question was about creating a clue for him/her to build appropriate query by himself. I shouldn't create whole system. If there was a column that I could use for ordering, I would use it, obviously.

Comment: You are using `UserID` in your `ORDER BY`. This is plain wrong, as it is not unique. What you should do? Tell him, that it is impossible and show reliable solutions. Just read my answer to find a sample ;-)

Comment: It's not wrong because if there is another column for ordering, we should consider userId as another ordering parameter, too.

Comment: This discussion is useless... Just believe me, that thousands of dollars where burried because of errors like yours above.. eot for me

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

This solution will work if the seqNum starts with 1 and increments by 1

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE
    (
        SeqNumber INT, 
        Note VARCHAR(MAX),
        UserID INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @T (SeqNumber, Note, UserID) VALUES
    (1, 'A', 20),
    (2, 'B', 20),
    (3, 'C', 20),
    (4, 'D', 20),
    (5, 'E', 20),
    (1, 'F', 20),
    (2, 'K', 20),
    (3, 'M', 20),
    (1, 'X', 20),
    (1, 'Y', 20)


    ;with cte1 as
    (
        select *,
        CASE WHEN LEAD(SeqNumber) OVER(partition by userId order by (select null))>SeqNumber THEN  LEAD(SeqNumber) OVER(order by (select null))
            ELSE NULL END as leadingSeq,
        ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by userId order by (select null)) as rowNum
         from @T
    )

    ,

    cte2
    As
    (

        select c1.SeqNumber,c1.UserId,ISNULL(c1.Note,'')+ISNULL(c2.Note,'') as Note 
        ,c2.leadingSeq,c2.rowNum    
        from cte1 c1
        LEFT JOIN cte1 c2 on c1.leadingSeq=c2.SeqNumber and c2.rowNum=c1.rowNum+1 and c1.SeqNumber=1 
        Where c1.SeqNumber=1 
        or c2.Note IS NOT NULL

        Union All

        Select c1.SeqNumber,c1.UserId,ISNULL(c1.Note,'')+ISNULL(c2.Note,'') as SecNote 
        ,c2.leadingSeq,c2.rowNum     
        from cte2 c1
        JOIN cte1 c2 on c1.leadingSeq=c2.SeqNumber and c2.rowNum=c1.rowNum+1



    )

    select UserId,Note 
    from cte2 
    where leadingSeq is null
```

Comment: No! This is a really dangerous approach! This might work in all your tests but breaks in production with silly and hardly findable errors. **The set is not sorted!** Your code uses `order by (select null)` in an `OVER`clause. This shows clearly, that you are relying on the given order. Never rely on the random sort order of any set. The only guaranteed order is the one you specify yourself using `ORDER BY` with (a) suitable column(s) with unique values.